# How to put a shortcode within an iframe?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, shortcode

I have a shortcode for a puzzle, but it is too wide for my wordpress text area.  I would like to put the shortcode within an iframe that allows for scrolling or opens in a new window (so maybe no iframe needed).  I cannot figure out how to do this.  I have tried using do_shortcode( '[h5p id="4"]' ) and just '[h5p id="4"]' in the src= part of the iframe, but I keep getting a 404 error.  The shortcode works on its own.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put it in an iframe, wrap it around a class and style it:

```
<div class="puzzle-wrapper">
  <?php echo do_shortcode( '[h5p id="4"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

and in your `style.css` add something similar to this:

```
.puzzle-wrapper{
   min-width: 500px;
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 500px;
}
```